# Join inet[] to inet

Tags: arrays, postgresql, join

I'm trying to join two tables:

`peering_autonomoussystem.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions` (which holds an array of ipv4 or ipv6 addresses)

and

`peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4` (which holds a simple ipv4 address)

and

`peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr6` (which holds a simple ipv6 address)

I'm having issues figuring out how to relate the `inet` value with the values from the unnested `inet[]` array so as to complete the join.

I've experimented with different variations to try and make something work, but I'm not making much headway.  I'm wondering if anyone might be able to throw some pointers my way?

```
select
 peering_autonomoussystem.asn,
 peering_autonomoussystem.name,
 unnest(peering_autonomoussystem.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions),
 peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4,
 peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr6,
 peeringdb_networkixlan.name
from
 (
 select unnest(peering_autonomoussystem.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions)
     from peering_autonomoussystem
 ) as inet(ip)
join
 peeringdb_networkixlan
on
 peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4 = inet.ip

ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "peering_autonomoussystem"
LINE 2:  peering_autonomoussystem.asn,
         ^
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 9
```

```
peering_manager=# select
peering_manager-#  peering_autonomoussystem.asn,
peering_manager-#  peering_autonomoussystem.name,
peering_manager-#  unnest(peering_autonomoussystem.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions),
peering_manager-#  peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4,
peering_manager-#  peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr6,
peering_manager-#  peeringdb_networkixlan.name
peering_manager-# from
peering_manager-#  peering_autonomoussystem
peering_manager-# join
peering_manager-#  peeringdb_networkixlan
peering_manager-# on
peering_manager-#  peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4 @> peering_autonomoussystem.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions
peering_manager-#
peering_manager-# ;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: inet @> inet[]
LINE 13:  peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4 @> peering_autonomoussystem....
                                         ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
peering_manager=#
```

Here are the data sets from the two tables that I'm working with:

```
peering_manager=# \d peering_autonomoussystem
                                                        Table "public.peering_autonomoussystem"
                    Column                    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                       Default
----------------------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+------------------------------------------------------
 id                                           | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('peering_autonomoussystem_id_seq'::regclass)
 asn                                          | bigint                   |           | not null |
 name                                         | character varying(128)   |           | not null |
 comment                                      | text                     |           | not null |
 ipv6_max_prefixes                            | integer                  |           | not null |
 ipv4_max_prefixes                            | integer                  |           | not null |
 updated                                      | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 irr_as_set                                   | character varying(255)   |           |          |
 ipv4_max_prefixes_peeringdb_sync             | boolean                  |           | not null |
 ipv6_max_prefixes_peeringdb_sync             | boolean                  |           | not null |
 irr_as_set_peeringdb_sync                    | boolean                  |           | not null |
 created                                      | timestamp with time zone |           |          |
 potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions | inet[]                   |           | not null |
 contact_email                                | character varying(254)   |           | not null |
 contact_name                                 | character varying(50)    |           | not null |
 contact_phone                                | character varying(20)    |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "peering_autonomoussystem_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "peering_autonomoussystem_asn_ec0373c4_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (asn)
Check constraints:
    "peering_autonomoussystem_ipv4_max_prefixes_check" CHECK (ipv4_max_prefixes >= 0)
    "peering_autonomoussystem_ipv6_max_prefixes_check" CHECK (ipv6_max_prefixes >= 0)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "peering_directpeeringsession" CONSTRAINT "peering_directpeerin_autonomous_system_id_691dbc97_fk_peering_a" FOREIGN KEY (autonomous_system_id) REFERENCES peering_autonomoussystem(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    TABLE "peering_internetexchangepeeringsession" CONSTRAINT "peering_peeringsessi_autonomous_system_id_9ffc404f_fk_peering_a" FOREIGN KEY (autonomous_system_id) REFERENCES peering_autonomoussystem(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

peering_manager=# select
 peering_autonomoussystem.asn,
 peering_autonomoussystem.name,
 unnest(peering_autonomoussystem.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions)
from
 peering_autonomoussystem limit 10;
  asn  |              name              |         unnest
-------+--------------------------------+-------------------------
  5400 | BT                             | 2001:504:1::a500:5400:1
  5400 | BT                             | 198.32.160.80
 21724 | Radiant Communications Toronto | 2001:504:1a::34:102
  8002 | Stealth Communications         | 2001:504:1::a500:8002:1
  8002 | Stealth Communications         | 2001:504:36::1f42:0:1
  8002 | Stealth Communications         | 206.82.104.194
 10835 | Visionary Communications, Inc. | 2001:504:16::2a53
 10835 | Visionary Communications, Inc. | 206.81.80.57
 23473 | Pavlov Media INC.              | 2001:504:17:115::224
 23473 | Pavlov Media INC.              | 206.126.115.224
(10 rows)

peering_manager=#
```

```
peering_manager=# \d peeringdb_networkixlan;
                                      Table "public.peeringdb_networkixlan"
   Column   |          Type          | Collation | Nullable |                      Default
------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer                |           | not null | nextval('peeringdb_networkixlan_id_seq'::regclass)
 asn        | bigint                 |           | not null |
 ipaddr6    | inet                   |           |          |
 ipaddr4    | inet                   |           |          |
 is_rs_peer | boolean                |           | not null |
 ix_id      | integer                |           | not null |
 name       | character varying(255) |           | not null |
 ixlan_id   | integer                |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "peeringdb_networkixlan_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Check constraints:
    "peeringdb_networkixlan_ix_id_check" CHECK (ix_id >= 0)
    "peeringdb_networkixlan_ixlan_id_check" CHECK (ixlan_id >= 0)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "peeringdb_peerrecord" CONSTRAINT "peeringdb_peerrecord_network_ixlan_id_97d3feaa_fk_peeringdb" FOREIGN KEY (network_ixlan_id) REFERENCES peeringdb_networkixlan(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED

peering_manager=# select
peering_manager-#  peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4,
peering_manager-#  peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr6,
peering_manager-#  name
peering_manager-# from
peering_manager-#  peeringdb_networkixlan
peering_manager-# where
peering_manager-#  ipaddr6 = '2001:504:1::a500:5400:1'
peering_manager-# or
peering_manager-#  ipaddr4 = '198.32.160.80'
peering_manager-# or
peering_manager-#  ipaddr6 = '2001:504:1a::34:102'
peering_manager-# or
peering_manager-#  ipaddr6 = '2001:504:1::a500:8002:1'
peering_manager-# or
peering_manager-#  ipaddr4 = '206.82.104.194'
peering_manager-# or
peering_manager-#  ipaddr6 = '2001:504:16::2a53'
peering_manager-# or
peering_manager-#  ipaddr4 = '206.81.80.57'
peering_manager-# or
peering_manager-#  ipaddr6 = '2001:504:17:115::224'
peering_manager-# or
peering_manager-#  ipaddr4 = '206.126.115.224';
     ipaddr4     |         ipaddr6         |                     name
-----------------+-------------------------+----------------------------------------------
 206.108.34.102  | 2001:504:1a::34:102     | TorIX
 206.126.115.224 | 2001:504:17:115::224    | Digital Realty New York
 198.32.160.80   | 2001:504:1::a500:5400:1 | NYIIX
 198.32.160.33   | 2001:504:1::a500:8002:1 | NYIIX
 206.81.80.57    | 2001:504:16::2a53       | SIX Seattle: MTU 1500
 206.82.104.194  | 2001:504:36::1f42:0:1   | DE-CIX New York: DE-CIX New York Peering LAN
(6 rows)

peering_manager=#
```

UPDATES:

After suggestions from @Laurenz Albe, I have refined the query as to use `ANY` which has produced positive results, although the query needs to be refined.  Using `pas.asn = 812` as an example:

```
select
 pas.asn asnumber,
 pas.name asname,
 pas.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions potential,
 pdbnil.ipaddr4 ipv4,
 pdbnil.ipaddr6 ipv6,
 pdbnil.name ixname
from
 peering_autonomoussystem pas
join
 peeringdb_networkixlan pdbnil
on
 pdbnil.ipaddr4 = any(pas.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions)
or
 pdbnil.ipaddr6 = any(pas.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions)
where pas.asn = 812;
 asnumber |    asname    |                            potential                             |     ipv4      |        ipv6        |     ixname
----------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------------+-----------------
      812 | Rogers Cable | {2001:504:12::14,198.32.134.32,2001:504:1a::34:29,206.108.34.29} | 198.32.134.32 | 2001:504:12::14    | Equinix Seattle
      812 | Rogers Cable | {2001:504:12::14,198.32.134.32,2001:504:1a::34:29,206.108.34.29} | 206.108.34.29 | 2001:504:1a::34:29 | TorIX
(2 rows)
```

My desired result for the above would be to see 4 rows, one for each of the values in the `potential` array.  I believed the `OR` in the join would have accomplished that, at least in part, but it seems not.

Comment: The first error you had is because `peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4 = peering_autonomoussystem.ip` should be `peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4 = inet.ip`. You aliased the sub-select so in the outer query Postgres doesn't know what `peering_autonomoussystem` is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Correcting that now produces an issue higher up in the query, which I'll modified the original post to reflect.

Comment: You might want to consider using aliases for your table names too, so you don't have to type out `peering_autonomoussystem.name` every time. You could be using something like `pas.name`. Try `FROM peering_autonomoussystem pas`.

Comment: Indeed.  I intend to add aliases after I get this part working. I had some issues adding them initially, so I opted to leave them out for the time being.

Comment: Are you looking for: `... from peering_autonomoussystem pa
  join peeringdb_networkixlan on pb.ipaddr4 = any(pa.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions);` (no unnest necessary, no derived table)

Comment: Yes, I'd also suggest using [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for your join condition:

1. An operator with `ANY`:

   ```
   peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4
   = ANY (peering_autonomoussystem.potential_internet_exchange_peering_session)
   ```

   This version can make use of a b-tree index on `peeringdb_networkixlan(ipaddr4)`.
2. The array “containment” operator:

   ```
   ARRAY[peeringdb_networkixlan.ipaddr4]
   <@ peering_autonomoussystem.potential_internet_exchange_peering_session
   ```

   This version can make use of a GIN index on `peering_autonomoussystem(potential_internet_exchange_peering_session)`.

You may want to try both and see which one is better for your case.

In general, it would have been better *not* to use an array if you want to join on individual array elements. Usually it is better to normalize the data in that case.

Comment: `ANY` did provide some better results, although it needs to be refined.  Original question modified with those results.

I wasn't able to get your second option to work:

`join
 peeringdb_networkixlan pdbnil
on
 ARRAY[pdbnil.ipaddr4] <@ pas.potential_internet_exchange_peering_session
;
ERROR:  column pas.potential_internet_exchange_peering_session does not exist
LINE 13:  ARRAY[pdbnil.ipaddr4] <@ pas.potential_internet_exchange_pe...
                                   ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "pas.potential_internet_exchange_peering_sessions".
`

Comment: Oh, and I'm only using the data in the database.  That is, I didn't write the application so I can't address your suggestion to not use arrays there.

Comment: That's just a naming error: you'll have to use the correct names. I cannot comment on the correctness of your results, because I don't know the semantics of the data. Using `OR` is normally a performance killer, since it prevents the use of indexes. Consider `UNION`ing two simple queries instead.